# Complete failure when reaching request.form

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I have a super serious issue which has completely stumped me.

I was playing with the IIS value in 'Maximum allowed content length' which can be seen in (IIS 7.0 on windows 7) IIS > Request filtering > right click white space > Edit feature settings.  I set this to 30 billion to experiment with uploading large files then restarted IIS.

Now ALL my systems work until a form is submitted.  The moment the submit button is clicked the destination page loads with this error:

> Request object error 'ASP 0104 : 80004005'
>
> Operation not Allowed
>
> /SERS/OHSIndex.asp, line 20

The code on line 20 is simply request.form - where ever I go the line number will change to which ever line the first request.form is.

So I set this  'Maximum allowed content length' back to 30000000 Bytes and did a  full re-start.  My issue is still there.   Hopefully someone knows how to solve this, I am completely stuck and all of my systems are inoperable.  Help..

Comment: Are you sure that the form does not have [enctype='multipart/form-data'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4526273/447356) in it? If it's there you can't access the Form in the usual way even if there's no actual file since the whole data is passed as raw stream.

Comment: I hope you're not too surprised to find a problem when you try to do something new with an obsolete technology. You should not be surprised to find that nobody has tried it: there are few people left even _using_ ASP, much less trying to do new things with it.

Comment: @John Altering this setting is nothing new.  I agree not may people building new systems using classic ASP however there are plenty of existing systems out there that continue to need work.  Trust me its still being used.  You have a nice day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your time and ideas.  As I said this was a complete show stopper for me, it simply had to be fixed ASAP.  After several hours of research I came to the conclusion I had a very rear issue since I could not find anybody having the same issue.  The error indicating it was something to do with fileSize, maxEntity, exceeding form control limit, exceeding the limit for a form etc.....  Well it simply was not any of those.  When I set an unusually high 'Maximum allowed content length' value and restarted IIS it tripped something out in a big way which could not be reverted.  A light bulb moment said IIS needed to be uninstalled and them re-installed.  This did fix it.

To answer the good people who asked questions:

no enctype='multipart/form-data' was not being used FYI .form and .querystring were problematic

changing the the 'Maximum allowed content length' property in IIS is the same as editing the  applicationHost.config file, there is no difference.  But yes I did check this, the values were the same as they should have been. As I said in my original post setting this value back to the default 30MB (for IIS 7)) did not chnage anything

200k is the default setting for IIS 6. I did mention I was using IIS 7.0, the default setting for 7.0 is actually 30mb.  Also the setting is not called 'AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed' in IIS 7 its called maxAllowedContentLength

Answer (score 3):

Maximum allowed content length is not for uploads, but for maximum response-length IIRC. Anyway, it seems you changing back your settings doesn't work. You may want to try editing this directly in the %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config file.

Alternatively, you can restore an old version of the config file, to restore the setting:
http://jshidell.com/2012/03/27/fixing-corrupted-applicationhost-config-file-in-iis-7/